# Different length with overtaking trains

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have two trains:
[image]

The length of  first train is $c$, and length of the second train is $b$, where  $c>b$; now suppose that train $1$ is moving with speed $a$ and train $2$ with speed $d$, where   $a<d$ (in other words the long train has lower speed than short one).

The question is: *when the short train overtakes long train?* In other words, after how  many hours will the short train overtakes the longer one?

My approach is the following, suppose this time be $t$ hours, because the first one is moving by $a$, it's length would be in generally $a\times t$, for the second it would be $d\times t$; but because $c>b$, then we should add the distance passed by short the train to the difference between lengths of this train, in other words:
$$
d\times t+(c-b)=a\times t
$$
Is it correct?

---

**EDIT:**

Let's say such example: the longer train (length $150$) has speed $70\,$km/h,and shorter one ($100$) with speed $90\,$km/h, how can it be resolved?

Comment: thanks @Andrea L for nice trains

Comment: we could upload real trains,just for joke  :D

Comment: You're welcome (Well, you're right, because it wolud be a real based proof). Regarding your question, have you tried to post it on Physics.SE?

Comment: but is it related to physics?

Comment: Your example, as edited, talks about *numbers with units*, and so there are equations describing their behaviour. If you post on *related* fields, you improve the chances of a complete answer.

Comment: if this question come on GRE,how  big probability is that it should be solved using physics fact?

Comment: It depends by the topic, but I think that in this case at least you wouldn't get ignored. And Yes, it can be definetly solved with Physics (as well as simple Math).

Comment: what about simple math?>

Comment: The basic equations that Alraxite shown.

Comment: but i have question,  we are adding difference of length  to larger one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10083/discussion-between-andrea-l-and-giorgi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation should be $a\cdot t+(c-b)=d\cdot t$, since the distance travelled by the second train ($=d\cdot t$) should be equal to the distance travelled by the first plus the difference by which train $1$ is longer than train $2$ (assuming they start at the same point).

Another way to look at this problem:

In the reference frame of train $1$, train $2$ is approaching train $1$ with speed $(d-a)$. Since the distance between them is $(c-b)$, the time for train $2$ to overtake train $1$ is $\dfrac{c-b}{d-a}$.

Comment: why  reversely?  we should add longer  train   difference between their length?

Comment: let say such example longer train with length  $150$ has speed  $70$km/H,and    shorter one $100$ meter with speed $90$km/H,let us do with this example please